# jQuery top menu and div z-index issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bar that scrolls and then sticks to the top of the page and it has buttons for some functions. This is done with jQuery.

The page's main div has a bunch of rows with text fields. If the z-index of the main div is set to -1, the div scrolls under the jQuery menu correctly but the textfields cannot be edited.

If the z-index is removed the main div scrolls over the jQuery menu and hides the buttons.

Does anyone know how I can have the main div slide under the jQuery menu and still allow input in the textfields?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
          <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
          <title>Database inventory</title>
          
            <style>
                fieldset {
                    border: 0;
                }
                label {
                    display: block;
                    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
                }
                select {
                    width: 250px;
                }
                .overflow {
                    height: 200px;
                }
                .demo_container { width:900px; margin: auto;}
                #demo_top_wrapper { margin:0 0 20px 0; width: 100%;}
                #demo_top 
                { 
                    height:80px; 
                    padding:20px 0 0 0; 
                    width: 900px:
                    margin: auto;
                }
                #demo_title
                {
                    background:url(images/trans-gray-60.png); 
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
                    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
                    background_color:white;
                }
                
                #list_title { font:40px Georgia, serif; }
                 
                /* our menu styles */
                #sticky_navigation_wrapper { 
                    width:900px; 
                    height:50px; 
                    margin: auto;
                }
                #sticky_navigation 
                { 
                    width:890px; 
                    height:50px; 
                    background:url(images/trans-black-60.png); 
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
                    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                }
                
                html, body 
                {
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;
                }
            </style>
            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                           
                $(function() {
         
                    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation
                    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;
                     
                    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
                    var sticky_navigation = function(){
                        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
                         
                        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
                        // otherwise change it back to relative
                        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
                            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0, 'width': '100%'});
                        } else {
                            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'width': '890px' });
                        }   
                    };
                     
                    // run our function on load
                    sticky_navigation();
                     
                    // and run it again every time you scroll
                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                         sticky_navigation();
                    });
                 
                });
                
                 $(function() {
                    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
                        .button()
                 });
            </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <form action="groceryListProcess.php" method="post">
            <div id="demo_top_wrapper">
                 
                    <!-- a header with a logo just to have some content before the menu -->
                    <div id="demo_top">
                        <div class="demo_container">
                            <div id="list_title">Add item from database</div>
                            <div id="list_info">#list_info</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- this will be our navigation menu -->
                    <div id="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
                        <div id="sticky_navigation">
                            <div class="demo_container">

                                <span style="vertical-align: top" id='addme'></span>
                                <span style="vertical-align: top" id='addnew'></span>
                                <span style="vertical-align: top" id='finish'></span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="">

                    <div style="width: 900px;
                        margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 20px; top: 10px; position: relative;
                        background-color: #f3f3f3; z-index: -1;">
                        
                        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 750px; ">
    <TABLE border=0><TR><TH style="text-align: left;" width = 50px></TH><TH style="text-align: left;" width = 50px></TH><TH style="text-align: left;" width = 60px> </TH><TH style="text-align: left;" width = 60px> </TH><TH style="text-align: left;" width = 600px> </TH><TH width = 25px></TH></TR><TR><TD colspan = 5><h2 style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px;">X</h2></TD></TR>
     <TR>
      <TD colspan=1></TD.
      <TD colspan = 3><h3 style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px;">X</h3>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;"> </TD>
      <TD style="text-align: left;"><B>Quantity</B></TD>
       <TD style="text-align: right;"><B>Price</B></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"><B>Item</B></TD>
      <TD><B></B>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_145' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_234' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_6' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_150' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_387' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_99' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_203' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_317' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_88' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_128' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_176' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_257' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_230' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_114' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_162' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_202' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_316' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_87' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_111' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_143' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_256' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_305' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR><TR><TD></TD></TR>
     <TR>
      <TD colspan=1></TD.
      <TD colspan = 3><h3 style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px;">X</h3>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;"> </TD>
      <TD style="text-align: left;"><B>Quantity</B></TD>
       <TD style="text-align: right;"><B>Price</B></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"><B>Item</B></TD>
      <TD><B></B>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_432' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_20' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_28' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_100' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_204' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_237' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_253' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_352' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_360' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_22' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_30' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_206' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_231' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_362' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_96' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_152' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_306' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_359' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_149' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_205' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_238' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_340' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_372' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_135' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR><TR><TD></TD></TR>
     <TR>
      <TD colspan=1></TD.
      <TD colspan = 3><h3 style="margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 6px;">X</h3>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;"> </TD>
      <TD style="text-align: left;"><B>Quantity</B></TD>
       <TD style="text-align: right;"><B>Price</B></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"><B>Item</B></TD>
      <TD><B></B>
      </TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_350' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_388' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_76' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_347' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_73' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_70' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD></TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">
       <input type='text' size='2' name='prod_421' value='0'/></TD>
      <TD style="text-align: right;">$X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;">X</TD>
      <TD style=" padding-left:10px;"></TD>
     </TR></TABLE>    
        
                
        <script>document.getElementById('addme').innerHTML = "<input type='submit' name='itemsadded' value='Add Items to List'/>";</script>
    <script>document.getElementById('addnew').innerHTML = "<input type='submit' id='itemsnew' name='itemsnew' value='Create New Item'/>";</script>
    <script>document.getElementById('finish').innerHTML = "<input type='submit' name='return' value='Cancel'/>";</script>
    <script>document.getElementById('list_info').innerHTML = "Available items: X";</script>
    <input type ='hidden' name='list_id' value='9'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider setting the z-index higher on the div that you want to be always visible, rather than making it negative on the div that contains the text `input`s - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index to sticky_navigation

```
#sticky_navigation 
{ 
    width:890px; 
    height:50px; 
    background:url(images/trans-black-60.png); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And remove z-index: -1 from the div.

update: Just saw this is exactly what fzzfzzfzz suggested in comment.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that a few times but based on your post I did not put it in the correct spot. Doing this does in-fact fix the problem. Thank you.